# How do you access the value of an SQL count () query in a Java program

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, count

I want to get to the value I am finding using the COUNT command of SQL. Normally I enter the column name I want to access into the getInt() getString() method, what do I do in this case when there is no specific column name.

I have used 'AS' in the same manner as is used to alias a table, I am not sure if this is going to work, I would think not.

```
Statement stmt3 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+lastTempTable+") AS count");
    while(rs3.next()){
    count = rs3.getInt("count");
    }
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Use aliases:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM ..
```

and then

```
rs3.getInt("total")
```

Comment: at least from my side, it needs first to call rs3.next() before calling rs3.getInt("total")

Comment: Thanks, I have something to ask from you, can we chat? Please

Comment: It definitely needs a call to rs3.next() (before getInt()). Otherwise, it will throw SQLException java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called

Answer (score 47):

The answers provided by [Bohzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho) and [Brabster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2362/brabster) will obviously work, but you could also just use:

```
rs3.getInt(1);
```

to get the value in the first, and in your case, only column.

Comment: From Javadoc: "Values can be retrieved using either the index number of the column or the name of the column. In general, using the column index will be more efficient."

Comment: This level of performance tuning really isn't important for most applications. Using column indexes exposes you to errors from columns moving around in your SQL query, which can be difficult to trace down. In this particular example (merely grabbing a record count), this isn't a problem, but it's something to keep in mind for application sustainability.

Comment: @PederRicer couldn't agree more.  Far too often people focus on micro-optimisations when clarity should (almost always) be the main goal of code

Answer (score 4):

I would expect this query to work with your program:

`"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM "+lastTempTable+")"`

(You need to alias the column, not the table)

Answer (score 2):

I have done it this way (example):

```
String query="SELECT count(t1.id) from t1, t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.email='"r@r.com"'";
int count=0;
try {
    ResultSet rs = DatabaseService.statementDataBase().executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next())
        count=rs.getInt(1);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing but I am getting NullPointerException(), can you help?

Answer (score 2):

```
        <%
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bala","bala","bala");
            if(con == null) System.out.print("not connected");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String myStatement = "select count(*) as total from locations";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(myStatement);
            int num = 0;
            while(rs.next()){
                num = (rs.getInt(1));
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);  
        }

        %>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Statement stmt3 = con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM "+lastTempTable+" ;");

count = rs3.getInt("count");
```

Comment: you need to call next() method to start the result set.
e.g.
while(recSet.next()){
num = recSet.getInt("...");
}

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to above but you can try like

```
public Integer count(String tableName) throws CrateException {
        String query = String.format("Select count(*) as size from %s", tableName);
        try (Statement s = connection.createStatement()) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = queryExecutor.executeQuery(s, query)) {
                Preconditions.checkArgument(resultSet.next(), "Result set is empty");
                return resultSet.getInt("size");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new CrateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```