# Get the value of COUNT(*) into an html table

Tags: html, sql, jdbc

I'm using a servlet to make the jdbc connection, write the PreparedStatements and execute ResultSets. I am able to display the data into a webpage just fine, however I also want to be able to count the number of entries. I know there are other ways to count how many rows I have using java code, but I want to use SQL statements and I saw this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name;
```

and made a preparedstatement and tried to execute. However, it is not returning the value of the count, I instead get 
 `"com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42ResultSet@4a9b1e8b"` or `"com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC42PreparedStatement@4a9b1e8b"` (because I tried getting the value of the count using both).

Basically, I am wondering how to get the count value in my html table from the servlet, not the long statements above.

Many thanks, I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute your SQL query with JDBC, you get a `Resultset` even when you get only one record with only one field as in your question.

You need to call the `getInt` or the [`getLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getLong(int)) method of your recordset to get the actual value.

```
long countValue = rs.getLong(1);
```

Have a look at Oracle's [documentation on JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)

You can also have a look at this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763659/how-do-you-access-the-value-of-an-sql-count-query-in-a-java-program)